# install driver for ricoh r5u870 webcam

Tags: drivers, webcam, sony, ricoh

I'm trying to install the driver for the webcam for my Sony laptop. I got the driver from [here](https://code.google.com/p/r5u870/), and I followed the installation guide. But I got the following error when I type in `make`:

```
~/Downloads/r5u870 $ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build M=/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870 V=0 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870/usbcam/usbcam_dev.o
/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870/usbcam/usbcam_dev.c: In function ‘usbcam_register_mod’:
/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870/usbcam/usbcam_dev.c:502:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘err’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   err("%s: Failed to allocate usbcam_minidrv_t", __FUNCTION__);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870/usbcam/usbcam_dev.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870/usbcam] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/xxx/Downloads/r5u870] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I neglected it and continued through the following steps, but the system still couldn't find the webcam, so I guess it didn't install. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

the r5u870 project have been updated. you could go to the project home page and get the new url. the project is hosted on github now.

the x86 version works. you can download it by clicking "download zip" in the right area  of the github page, and other steps are just same as before.

if you are using the x64 version of linux, you may try the master branch on github, but it may not work, since the author said he doesn't have a x64 machine to develop and test.